залученість до спільноти
Можна сказати "залученість до спільноти" відносно активної життєвої позиції?


Активна життєва позиція – стійка позиція особистості, спрямована на зміну і перетворення суспільних умов життя відповідно до свого переконання, поглядів і совісті.

Якщо погодитись з таким означенням активної життєвої позиції та й взагалі зі значенням слова активна, то залученість до спільноти не може бути синонім до цього поняття, адже можна бути залученим у справи спільноти пасивно, наприклад, всі йдуть на танці і я йду або всіх женуть на суботник і мене з ними.
